# Replacing NAs for numerical variables with median

Tags: r

My dataframe is a csv read into r using fread:

```
df <- fread("df.csv", stringsAsFactors = T)
```

Here is a screenshot of the partial dataframe (the entire dataframe is 1177 rows long and consist of a few hundred NAs in certain cells):
[image: Screenshot of the partial dataframe]

This is my R code to replace NAs for each cell in the dataframe, df with the median of the respective column.

```
  for (j in 1:length(df)){
    if(is.na(df[i][j])){
      if (class(df[[j]])== 'numeric' || class(df[[j]])== 'integer' ){
        df[i][j]= median(df[[j]], na.rm=T)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

There is this error currently:There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)

I am guessing there is something wrong with how I refer to each cell of the dataframe df, which is df[i][j] currently. Can I get some advice?

Comment: can you show an example of the structure of your data?

Comment: why not use r as intended and do `df[is.na(df[,i]),] <- median(df[[i]], na.rm=T)` you can run a for loop to go through all the columns or use a tidyverse solution (like `mutate(across()) or similar`)

Comment: @D.J, your first code will replace with the median across all columns, which is not in spirit of the outer `for (j ...)` loop.

Comment: @DavideLorino I have included a screenshot!

Comment: @r2evans true, it should be more like `df[,1][is.na(df[,1])] <- median(df[,1], na.rm = T)`

Comment: Please do not post (only) an image of code/data/errors: it breaks screen-readers and it cannot be copied or searched (ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No loop required:

### base R

```r
diam <- head(ggplot2::diamonds)
diam$table[3:4] <- NA
diam$x[c(1,5)] <- NA
diam
# # A tibble: 6 x 10
#   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5    55   326 NA     3.98  2.43
# 2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8    61   326  3.89  3.84  2.31
# 3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9    NA   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
# 4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4    NA   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
# 5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3    58   335 NA     4.35  2.75
# 6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8    57   336  3.94  3.96  2.48
isnum <- sapply(diam, is.numeric)
diam[isnum] <- lapply(diam[isnum], function(z) ifelse(is.na(z), median(z, na.rm = TRUE), z))
diam
# # A tibble: 6 x 10
#   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5  55     326  4.00  3.98  2.43
# 2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8  61     326  3.89  3.84  2.31
# 3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9  57.5   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
# 4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4  57.5   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
# 5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3  58     335  4.00  4.35  2.75
# 6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8  57     336  3.94  3.96  2.48
```

(`ggplot2` is only used here as a source of a diverse dataset. Otherwise this solution is base-R.)

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
diam %>%
  mutate(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if_else(is.na(.), median(., na.rm = TRUE), as.numeric(.))))
# A tibble: 6 x 10
#   carat cut       color clarity depth table price     x     y     z
#   <dbl> <ord>     <ord> <ord>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1  0.23 Ideal     E     SI2      61.5  55     326  4.00  3.98  2.43
# 2  0.21 Premium   E     SI1      59.8  61     326  3.89  3.84  2.31
# 3  0.23 Good      E     VS1      56.9  57.5   327  4.05  4.07  2.31
# 4  0.29 Premium   I     VS2      62.4  57.5   334  4.2   4.23  2.63
# 5  0.31 Good      J     SI2      63.3  58     335  4.00  4.35  2.75
# 6  0.24 Very Good J     VVS2     62.8  57     336  3.94  3.96  2.48
```

### Side note

It appears that your data is or should be grouped/stratified (`group` among others). What you're talking about is "imputation", and replacing missing data with the median should arguably be done by group whenever possible so as to not introduce bias into your analysis. There are numerous ways to approach this, too many to start discussing here, but I implore you to look into imputation and, if necessary, open a new question into best imputation strategies for this data (on https://stats.stackexchange.com/, likely).

Comment: to be fair, lapply is kind of a loop

Comment: Everything that is "vectorized" is a loop as well, somewhere in the code. Perhaps it would be clearer to say "no user-coded loop"?

Comment: where(is.integer) seems to whiff on doubles for obvious reasons, maybe broaden the if condition.

Comment: Yup, thanks, that was in my initial iteration but I had a moment of cross-testing that I did not fix/remove.

Comment: its still in your dplyr step

Comment: Refresh your page, it is not there.

Comment: maybe update the data output to reflect the change as well, the x field has NAs in it from when you ran it as where(is.integer)

Comment: Ugh, good call ... that's what I get for updating this in an airport terminal in between flights ... thank you

Comment: @r2evans thank you for ur help even at a terminal :) will read up about imputation too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do the following `mutate` step for any field that has NAs in it.

```
df %>%
   mutate(BMI = case_when(is.na(BMI) ~ median(BMI), TRUE ~ BMI)
```

Comment: If you're only working on one column at a time with only one condition, is there a reason you chose to not use `if_else`? I like `case_when` for anything that requires nesting, but in this case it seems unnecessary (`if_else` will be faster with larger data).

Comment: user said hes got 1100 rows and optimizing something that isnt a mission critical piece of software is performative engineering.